facing Invalid intermediate certificate with a governmental site! [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
I'm trying to fetch some data from a market exchange website using python with httpx library.
when I make a request to the api I get an error message..
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
but if I ignore the ssl verification  verify = False I could bypass this issue and get the desired data.
I have checked the website ssl certificate and the result was that there is Invalid intermediate certificate and it uses TLSv1 protocol.
My question here..
could they use the invalid certificate intentionally?
as I have read some websites use this method to prevent scraping data somehow. but, would a governmental website use this method too?!

"could they use the invalid certificate intentionally?" - unlikely. More likely a (not uncommon) broken setup. Since browsers usually work around this (but others don't) it often does not get noticed.

One common problem with web sites is that the certificate chain they send is incomplete, that means not only the root CA cert is missing (which is expected for a TLS handshake) but also one or more intermediate CA certificate are missing. Web browsers have large lists of common intermediate CA certs they can use to "fill the gaps". Other TLS implementations and CA lists work as specified and only contain the root CA list which then can lead to such an error. Use an online test like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to verify the server certificate chain.
